# PySpark External Table all fields are empty

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-lab

I've created a new df2:

```
schema2 = "Product STRING, Quantity INT"
data4 = [('Pen', 9),('Pineappple', 22),('Apple', 12),('Pen', 13)]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data4, schema2)
```

Next, I would like to turn it into an External Table (Unmanaged):

```
df2.write.format('parquet').save("ExternalTables/ppap_nm") 

df2.write.mode('overwrite').option("path", "ExternalTables/ppap_nm").saveAsTable("ppap_nm")
```

Now, if I try to select data from our newly created table `ppap_nm` I get the following `WARN`.

```
spark.sql("select * from ppap_nm").show()
```

```
+-------+--------+
|Product|Quantity|
+-------+--------+
+-------+--------+

22/03/11 14:17:36 WARN HadoopFSUtils: The directory file:/home/corbanez/Documents/PySpark/spark-warehouse/desp.db/ExternalTables/ppap_nm was not found. Was it deleted very recently?
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I try another method for table creation?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

1. Path must be absolute (You should have gotten an error for that)
2. Only one write operation is needed

---

```
schema2 = "Product STRING, Quantity INT"
data4 = [('Pen', 9),('Pineappple', 22),('Apple', 12),('Pen', 13)]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data4, schema2)

df2.write.mode('overwrite').option("path", "/ExternalTables/ppap_nm").format('parquet').saveAsTable("ppap_nm")

spark.table('ppap_nm').show()
```

---

```
+----------+--------+
|   Product|Quantity|
+----------+--------+
|Pineappple|      22|
|     Apple|      12|
|       Pen|      13|
|       Pen|       9|
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: It worked! Just set an absolute path, then I got the expected table. Weirdly I did not get an error. But either way, thank you!!